# Company::find(1)->departments returns null from relationship issues

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making a few tables having one to many relationships and I also have one to one relationships but if I solve this why it is not working maybe I can solve one to one as well.
I will provide some codes for you to have a look at.

when I go to tinker and type like "Company::find(1)->deparments", it returns null. when I check the database, foreign key is correctly added. 
I also set the primary key in model.

Company table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('company_id');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('company_name',100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Department Table

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('department_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('company_id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('department_name',100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Company Model

```
  protected $primaryKey = 'company_id';

    Protected $table='companies';
    Protected $fillable=['phone','company_name'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'user_id');
    }
```

Department Model

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'department_id';

    protected $table = 'departments';
    protected $fillable = ['department_name'];
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class,'company_id');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'department_id');
    }
```

Comment: There's a typo: `Company::find(1)->departments` Have you defined a `departments` relationship?

Comment: Thank you mate. I missed creating relationship from company to departments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the department relationship in Company Model inorder to call this command.

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Department::class,'department_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this after creating relationship,

```
Company::with(['deparments'])->findOrFail(1);
```

Hope this helps :)